# D3js Dynamically draw multiple separate lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am relatively new to D3js. I went through the basics of a tutorial on [Udemy by Adam Janes](https://www.udemy.com/masteringd3js/learn/v4/overview). I want to create multiple separate lines that can connect nodes on the following map. 
[image: The green dots are nodes, I want to use a line to show a connection between the nodes]
The green dots are nodes, I want to use a line to show a connection between the nodes. The data used to draw the nodes:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5bd940c7c917bd051c995dca",
    "whereID": "100110060000",
    "SN": 67,
    "position": [
      1085.2642276422764,
      564.0921409214093
    ],
    "trainStatus": 0,
    "missionSN": 1
  },
  ...
  {
    "_id": "5bc6e4e5603d6112000e028a",
    "whereID": "100110060000",
    "SN": 32,
    "position": [
      1037.511770244821,
      440.9957627118644
    ],
    "trainStatus": 0,
    "missionSN": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bc6e4e5603d6112000e0289",
    "whereID": "100110060000",
    "SN": 31,
    "position": [
      1181.314736346516,
      357.909604519774
    ],
    "trainStatus": 0,
    "missionSN": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bc6e4e5603d6112000e0288",
    "whereID": "100110060000",
    "SN": 30,
    "position": [
      1433.7688323917137,
      309.9752824858757
    ],
    "trainStatus": 0,
    "missionSN": 1,
    "connectedNodes": [
      {
        "SN": 62,
        "position": [
          1459.3338041431261,
          333.4098399246704
        ],
        "whereID": "100110060000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bc6e4e5603d6112000e0287",
    "whereID": "100110060000",
    "SN": 29,
    "position": [
      1702.201035781544,
      308.91007532956684
    ],
    "trainStatus": 0,
    "missionSN": 1,
    "connectedNodes": [
      {
        "SN": 61,
        "position": [
          1732.026836158192,
          333.4098399246704
        ],
        "whereID": "100110060000"
      },
      {
        "SN": 62,
        "position": [
          1459.3338041431261,
          333.4098399246704
        ],
        "whereID": "100110060000"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

With the above data, I am trying to use `position` values to create the {x1, y1} values and connecting them with `connectedNodes.position` values creating {x2, y2}. The problem I am encountering is that, there can be multiple `connectedNodes`, so how do I draw the line?

This is what I have:

```
view = svg.append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('class', 'view-container')
    .append('g')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('class', 'view')
nodeUpdate = view.selectAll('.trainingNode').data(useData);
nodeEnter = nodeUpdate.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'trainingNode');
nodeEnter
    .append('line')
      .attr('x1', d => {
        if (d.connectedNodes && d.connectedNodes.length > 0)
          return d.position[0]
      })
      .attr('x2', d => {
        if (d.connectedNodes && d.connectedNodes.length > 0)
          return d.position[0]
      })
      .attr('y1', d => {
        if (d.connectedNodes && d.connectedNodes.length > 0)
          return d.connectedNodes[0].position[0]
      })
      .attr('y2', d => {
        if (d.connectedNodes && d.connectedNodes.length > 0)
          d.connectedNodes[0].position[0]
      })
      .style('stroke', 'black')
      .style('stroke-width', 5)
```

**EDIT**: After a while on reading up about force simulations, I have successfully added lines linking the nodes together, however it only shows properly for the top half of the canvas.

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
let links = []
useData.forEach(ud => {
  if (ud.connectedNodes && ud.connectedNodes.length > 0) {
    ud.connectedNodes.forEach(node => {
      links.push({
        source: node.SN,
        target: ud.SN
      })
    })
  }
})

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(d => d.SN))

simulation.nodes(useData)

simulation.force('link')
  .links(links)

let line = nodeEnter.append('line')
  .data(links)
  .attr('x1', d => Math.floor(d.source.position[0] * widthRatio))
  .attr('y1', d => Math.floor(d.source.position[1] * widthRatio))
  .attr('x2', d => Math.floor(d.target.position[0] * widthRatio))
  .attr('y2', d => Math.floor(d.target.position[1] * widthRatio))
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', 3)
```

Comment: look at force simulation example with links between the nodes

Comment: @rioV8 Hello, so I used the force simulation and got the links to show up, however I ran into a problem that I have no idea why it is happening. The top half of the nodes will show the links but the bottom half only show some of them even though I have connected them. Do you perhaps know why this is happening?

Comment: @rioV8Okay so I figured out why it isn't printing the bottom ones properly, it is because `useData` has a length of 67, and `links` has a length of over 100, so it couldn't render all of the links. Not sure if I am correct, is there a way to make sure that `forceSimulation` loads all of the links?

Comment: you don't need the force simulation only the way how it draws the links. Why store the full pos of nodes in connected list when you can look this up in the node list by id. Without a full running example it is **very** hard to tell what is wrong.